# How to Choose a New Snapshot Version

Tags: java, maven, version-control, versioning, snapshot

If I understand correctly, a SNAPSHOTs are done before a release such that 1.0-SNAPSHOT eventually becomes 1.0.

So after release 1.0, how do I decide to now change the version to 1.1-SNAPSHOT, or 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  You would normally change the version either by hand or by an automated process to indicate what version it's at.  Was there something else that you were looking to clarify on this?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps because I am confused I am not able to phrase the question properly. When I am writing code early in my development, I don't know if I will be making major or minor changes. I don't know whether my next version will be 1.0.1, or 1.1 (depending on how much I end up changing)

Comment: It depends on the company, but so long as you follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), then it should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Alright, that makes enough sense to me. I guess it's more difficult for me to choose because I am working on a personal project, so I move at a fast pace because I don't have to review with anyone else. So sometimes a small addition turns in to a big one because CI is not that important. I will keep these things in mind for when I work at a company and I won't worry too much about version numbers for my own project.

Comment: Mark - If it is your own personal project, then who really cares what your version number is.

Comment: @ScaryWombat this is true, but there is the off chance that I invite others to the project in the future. I'm sure I can figure it out if needed. The reason I asked the question was because I thought this may be a common problem but I can see now how with collaborative projects with big groups of people, this is done more slowly and there is not the same confusion that I have. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 here. When I just released `{x}.{y}.{z}` version, I don't know yet if my next release is going to be major, minor or bugfix-only, hence don't know if I should assign it `{x+1}.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, `{x}.{y+1}.0-SNAPSHOT` or `{x}.{y}.{z+1}-SNAPSHOT` version, so question remains valid IMO

Answer (score -3):

A good write-up on how to version your application: http://semver.org/

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as
>   extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.